# Travis collecting ... The command "pytest" exited with 1

Tags: python, pytest, travis-ci

For the project https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/play-chess-with-a-webcam and the travis configuration:

```
# see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/
language: python
# python versions to be tested
python:
#  - "2.7" # see https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/gremlin-python-tutorial/issues/7
  - "3.7"
# command to install dependencies
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
# command to run tests
script:
  - pytest
```

I get the error message:

```
collecting ... The command "pytest" exited with 1.
```

in the travis environment. While locally i get:

```
============================== test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.2.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
rootdir: /Users/wf/source/python/play-chess-with-a-webcam
collected 5 items                                                               

test_OpenCV_version.py .                                                  [ 20%]
test_Video.py ..                                                          [ 60%]
test_findBoard.py ..                                                      [100%]

=============================== 5 passed in 7.03s ===============================
```

**What is the reason for the error?**

**How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the reason for the error?**
The tests have OpenCV GUI output and the headless situation let's pytest choke.

**How can I fix it?**
add the following to .travis.yml

```
# allow gui output
services:
  - xvfb
```